How to update Facebook SDK for IOS to the latest version?
enter image description here
I am trying to update the facebook sdk for ios on my facebook business account, before it was a lower version everything was working fine, but recently i got a warning to update the sdk to the latest version, after updating to 17.0.0 i still see the same warning and it doesn't work . After contacting support, they give me the same message again "you need to update the SDK to the latest version". What did I do wrong?
I did everything according to this instruction
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/
enter image description here
after failure, I tried to remove the dependency and install everything again, i created a new one app in the Facebook developer account .Not Help

Xcode Version 15.2
deployment IOS Version 15
Facebook Sdk 17.0.0 was added first time via CocoaPod then via Swift Packages
Audience Network SDK 6.15.0 added

my AppDelegate.swift
enter image description here
